# How to place included rst content from toctree after parent content in Sphinx latex

Tags: python-sphinx, sections, toctree

I'm writing a sphinx documentation for use in generating both html and latex output.

Some of my `rst` files are structured as follows:

```
My chapter title
=====================

.. toctree::
   :hidden:
   :maxdepth: 2

   folder/subchapter1
   folder/subchapter2


Chapter introduction
--------------------------
Brief introduction...
```

This works as intended in my html output - but for my latex build, I'm getting the following order when building my pdf:

```
My chapter title
subchapter1
[contents of subchapter 1]
subchapter2
[contents of subchapter 2]
Chapter introduction
Brief introduction...
```

The intended order would be as below:

```
My chapter title
Chapter introduction
Brief introduction...
subchapter1
[contents of subchapter 1]
subchapter2
[contents of subchapter 2]
```

Is there some way to tell sphinx via the `conf.py` that this should be the ordering?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution was simply to move the toctree down below the content.